# php form never shows anything whenever it's submitted

Tags: php, html, string, forms

```
<html>
<body>
hi!

<?php 
Hi!

if(htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"] == "hey"))
{
Hi!
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

It's probably something small, but I can't figure out why my message never shows when I try running it. I tried echo, print, and just typing the text out on screen, and I can never get the php form to run, it's always blank. Perms are set to 644. The form submitting the block of code's below...

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't just say `Hi!`, you have to `echo` it

Comment: You are going to want to `print` or `echo` your `Hi!` statements. Is there anything in your log files?

Comment: If you are able to, you should turn on error reporting which would have pointed you to the issue. As everyone else has stated, you need to either echo it out or close your php tag, write it, then reopen your tag. <?php if () { echo "Hi"; } ?> or <?php if () { ?>Hi<?php } ?>

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments and answers from other users regarding your code missing an `echo` or `print()` on "Hi", your brackets are mixed up:

`if(htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"] == "hey"))` should be :

```
if (htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]) == "hey")
```

Comment: Exactly...  having the closing paren in the wrong place completely changes the meaning of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, to print data within php you need to use echo:

```
<?php 
echo "Hi!"; // <--- here

if(htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]) == "hey") // <---- here you was a syntax error too
{
echo "Hi!"; // <--- here
}
?>
```

Or other related functions like: print, print_r, var_dump

Answer (score 0):

you couldn't just write html inside php without echoing it..

```
<html>
<body>
hi!

<?php 

if(htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]) == "hey")
{
echo "Hi!";
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```